# C# Form add controls on runtime

Tags: c#, forms, asynchronous

Hello I have difficulties adding controls to my form on runtime.

```
    static Form1 f2 = new Form1();

    async public static void startTimer()
    {
        //await Task.Run(() => f2.ShowDialog());

        stopWatch.Start();
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.Interval = 50;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
        await Task.Run(() => f2.ShowDialog());

    }

    public static void splitTime()
    {
        TextBox txtRun = new TextBox();
        txtRun.Name = "txtDynamic";
        txtRun.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 18 + (20 * 2));
        txtRun.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 25);
        f2.Controls.Add(txtRun);        
     }
```

Any idea why this is failing ? I think because of the async but don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Where is your on_load event?

Comment: Where are you calling `splitTime` method? `why this is failing` what does this mean? Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate ()
{
TextBox txtRun = new TextBox();
        txtRun.Name = "txtDynamic";
        txtRun.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 18 + (20 * 2));
        txtRun.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 25);
        f2.Controls.Add(txtRun);    

});
```

Comment: This works, I will accept it as an answer as soon as I can. Thanks, can you also maybe explain shortly why this is the solution in orde for me to understand.

Comment: Also any idea how I can access this created control from other function as f2.txtRun.Text = "test"; obviously will not work and be recognized.

Comment: IMO, this should not be the accepted answer. This question seems a lot like the https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem .Yes, this answer seemed to have fixed part of the question you asked, but several valuable questions were left open in the comments that help frame your whole question. One big question is, why are you needing the `ShowDialog` call to be async? That seems like a flaw, and the root of both of your described symptoms so far.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I need it because the main application needs to keep running and in the background an other dialog should be showed and activated with live info while the background dialog still is active and not blocked / freeze.